# Why is the Gulf of Alaska not a Bay? What is the difference between a Gulf and a Bay?

Tags: oceanography, water, land-surface, land

**Since the mouth of this water body is actually very wide, why do we call it a Gulf?**

**What exactly is the difference between a Gulf and a Bay?**

[image]

Comment: a gulf has a narrower opening than a bay this means that the gulf of alaska is a bay :) https://keydifferences.com/difference-between-bay-and-gulf.html

Comment: Not to be picky, but I think the Gulf of Alaska would be classified as a bight rather than a bay because of dimensions: https://www.worldatlas.com/articles/bay-bight-fjord-and-sound-similarities-and-differences-between-these-coastal-landforms.html

Comment: This question is about language, not science. There are plenty of concepts that the English language has several words for. There is NO way to define these terms to make a meaningful distinction.

Comment: It depends on the map projection you look at. On the one you posted it appears wide, but if you take a Mollweide projection for instance (or even worse, a sinusoidal projection), it will appear much narrower. ;)

Comment: I personally think that these distinctions are important, fit the site, and definitely have a scientific base. The fact that historically the nomenclature has been used inconsistently doesn't mean that there isn't a scientific reason for them.

Comment: Also for reference: https://www.waterencyclopedia.com/A-Bi/Bays-Gulfs-and-Straits.htm